# Change locale param in current URL in a ZF2 application

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2, translation

Basically I want to be able to redirect the visitor to the current translated page equivalent with a translated URL.

I have both content and url translation in place and all my routes start with the `:locale` param.

How can I get the current URL translated ?

ex: On the page http://domain.com/fr/actualites I want to have a link that point to http://domain.com/en/news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution shortly after asking this question.

First retreive the current route name used :

```
<?php
$sm = $this->getHelperPluginManager()->getServiceLocator();
$route = $sm->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
?>
```

And then display URL with the `:locale` param changed while asking the helper to keep and translate current URL params:

```
<?php echo $this->url($route, ['locale' => 'en'], ['force_canonical' => true, 'locale' => 'en_US'], true) ?>
```

- The first `'locale'` is for the `/en` in the url
- The second `'locale'` is to declare the language to use for the route translator
- The `'force_canonical' => true` is only here to display the full URL instead of the relative URL.
- The last `true` is to tell the URL helper to use the current request params to assemble the URL